# What is the most efficient way to find the sum of all nodes' values in an n-ary tree, where each node's value is the sum of it's children +1?

Tags: graph, tree, nodes, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

Suppose we have an n-ary tree. All leaves in the tree have a value of **k**.

All other nodes have a value of 1 + the sum of its children's values.

What is the most efficient way to find the sum of the values of all nodes in the tree?

Side question: Since this is a subtask of a problem I'm currently working on I wonder, can the aforementioned sum be calculated on the go while generating the tree itself (I'm generating it with BFS from another graph)?

Comment: Assuming you don't have any information about the tree beyond the tree data structure itself, the "obvious" solution which walks the whole tree solves this in linear time, and you can't do better than linear time. Is there anything else you would be able to take advantage of?

Comment: The _the sum of the values of all nodes in the tree_ is the value of the root node -1. To calculate it while generating the tree you'll have to work from the leaves up. More information is need (and an example would be nice) to have a more detailed answer.

Comment: @c0der I don't know how you've reached that conclusion; the nodes all have non-negative values, so the sum (which includes the root node's value) cannot be less than the value of the root node.

Comment: @kaya3   "_All other nodes have a value of 1 + the sum of its children's values_" so the value of the root node, minus 1 is equal to the sum of all its children. The sum of the whole tree should be (value of the root node, minus 1)* 2

Comment: @c0der But not every other node is a child of the root node. Take e.g. A -> B -> C as a counterexample with k = 5, then C's value is 5 because it's a leaf, B's value is 6 because C is the only child, and the root node A's value is 7 because B is the only child. The sum is then 18, which is not (7 - 1) * 2.

Comment: @kaya3 you are right